# Creating a function that runs even if some files don't import properly

Tags: r

I've got a function to import multiple files. It is shown below:

```
 tucson_function<- function (x) {
   df <- read.tucson(x)
   final1<-as.data.frame(df)
   final2<-rownames_to_column(final1, 'year')
   site_ID <- sub('\\.rwl$', '', x)
   final2<- cbind(final2, site_ID)
   final3<-reshape2::melt(final2)
    }
```

The `read.tucson` is from a package `dplR` and used to import files of .rwl extension. I then import the files in the following way:

```
asia_data<-lapply(asia, tucson_function)
```

The issue is that the `tucson_function` fails for several files in the folder. That is fine, but in the current form it stops the rest of the files from uploading (it throws a warning and stops the function). I would like the function to 'ignore' the warning and discard the failing files, and continue importing the rest of the files.

How could I do this?

Comment: `?try` ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `possibly` from `purrr` or `tryCatch` from `base R`.  With `possibly`, specify the value to return in `otherwise` in case it fails

```
library(purrr)
ptucson_function <- possibly(tucson_function, otherwise = NA)
map(asia, ptucson_function)
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `tryCatch`

```
lapply(asia, function(x) tryCatch(tucson_function(x), error=function(e)  NA))
```